# how to get user Roles and client roles when authenticate from keycloak

Tags: java, jhipster, keycloak

when authenticate user on jhipster always granted roles are ROLE_USER
despite I defined ROLE_ADMIN for the user on role mapping in  on key-cloak user and add role to client role   and

Answer (score 0):

There is an example to get roles of an user in your client realm

`KeycloakPrincipal<?> kp = (KeycloakPrincipal<?>)fc.getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();`

This line return the user roles in your client ID **"yourClientID"**
`kp.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken().getResourceAccess("yourClientID").getRoles();`